# Invalid type for parameter Body in Amazon S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I'm trying to save python list `data_issues` (of type `<class 'list'>`) using Glue to an Amazon S3 bucket but I'm getting below error:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value: 

[('document_entity_sdi', Exception("For column, int and YES don't match.")), 
    ('account_status_sdi', Py4JJavaError('An error occurred while calling o80.getCatalogSink.\n', JavaObject id=o654)), 
    ('account_transaction_fcs_status', Py4JJavaError('An error occurred while calling o80.getCatalogSink.\n', JavaObject id=o797)),
    ('purchase_order_agreement', Py4JJavaError('An error occurred while calling o80.getCatalogSink.\n', JavaObject id=o21565))], 

type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object
```

I tried this workaround to convert the list `bytes(data_issues)` but doesn't work:

```
BUCKET = 'bucket_name'
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
keyid = 'keyID'

print("Uploading S3 object with SSE-KMS")
s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET,
          Key='encrypt-key',
          Body=bytes(data_issues),
          ServerSideEncryption='aws:kms',
          SSEKMSKeyId=keyid)
print("Saving to S3, Done")
```

Comment: `data_issues` is the list I want to print. `data_issues = [('value', Exception("text value")), ('value', {values, values})]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that your `data_issues` is a list of strings. You can convert it to bytes in a number of ways. One would would be to make json of it first and then turn it into `bytes`:

```
Body=bytes(json.dumps(data_issues).encode())
```

Update:

If you have non-string values, you can do:

```
Body=bytes(json.dumps(data_issues, default=str).encode())
```

Depending on what exactly do you want to do, you can also `pickle` your payload. This would allow you to reconstruct the data later on if its not suited for json format.

Comment: Got an error `Object of type Exception is not JSON serializable`

Comment: @marcin2x4 What exactly is `data_issues`? Your code shows it is just list of strings: `['value', 'value2', ... 'valueN']`. If is not, then your question is not representative of your actual code, and its rather impossible to help you.

Comment: `data_issues` is `<class 'list'>`

Comment: @marcin2x4 I mean, exactly what it is? What are the elements in the `data_issues`. Are they really just strings as in your question?  `['value', 'value2', ... 'valueN']`

Comment: I'll try to open private chat and paste the data 2 you.

Comment: @marcin2x4 I updated the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236642/discussion-between-marcin2x4-and-marcin).

Comment: Unfortunately, `Object of type Exception is not JSON serializable` error pops again.

Comment: @marcin2x4 How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Comment: `Body=bytes(json.dumps(data_issues, default=str).encode())` did the trick! I also had to fix S3 path syntax, missing last `/` caused `access denied` error.